# textField.getText() can only take Strings, what if I want it to take an int?

Tags: java, string, int, gettext

I have a problem. I have an UI which contains several textfields in which you are suppose to enter random characters/numbers/letters.

```
 String socSecNbr = textFieldCustomerSocSecNbr.getText();
```

In this case, of course, I want to change the socSecNbr to an int. But then the method getText() does not work.

What do I have to change it to? I tried the following code, but it still doesn't work:

```
 int socSecNbr = textFieldCustomerSocSecNbr.getInstance();
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which language and UI technology do you use?

Comment: @AndrásKerekes Dang, good question. I assumed this was Java :O

Comment: @LewsTherin Even with the assumption it is java (which with getInstance() could be a possible) it could be absolutely any UI framework, swing, SWT, GWT (and GWT extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can do this:

```
  int value =  Integer.valueOf(textFieldCustomerSocSecNbr.getText());
```

Comment: textFieldCustomerSocSecNbr.setText(tmpCustomer.getSocSecNbr());

in this case I get the error:

Error(323,13): method setText(int) not found in class java.awt.TextField


What should I change it to in order to make it work?

I am a noob, yes I know :)

Comment: never mind, I got it to work! Thanks a lot Haris! 100000 reps to you my friend!

Comment: by the way, if I would like a double instead of int is there a similar code to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the string into integer by using

```
int a= Integer.parseInt(socSecNbr);
```

Comment: if I would like a double instead of int is there a similar code to do it?